# Format a cell based on conditions in different cells

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am trying to highlight a cell red if the date is more than 28 days old and the next cell is blank. I tried to do conditional formatting by using the following rule:

```
=and(a1 < today()-28, b1="not blank")
```

It didn't give me an error, but it also didn't highlight the appropriate cells.

Why is this not working?

Comment: if you put the following formula in an empty cell does it return TRUE or FALSE?  `=istext(A1)`

Comment: Had to add )) on the end for it to accept but that still did not work :(

Comment: Cell A1 should only highlight if it is OVER 28 days old AND Cell B1 IS blank - this will indicate to me that action is required (as a completion date is not in cell B1)

Comment: Would `B1` typically hold a number or a text string?

Comment: It will either be blank or hold a date

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want your conditional formatting to apply to a given cell when `A1` is more than 28 days older than today's date AND when `B1` ***does not contain a date***.

If so, try using this for your conditional format formula:

`=AND($A1<TODAY()-28,NOT(ISNUMBER($B1)),$B1>0)`

**EXPLANATION:**

With the `AND` function wrapping all of this up, all three conditions

`$A1<TODAY()-28`

&

`NOT(ISNUMBER($B1))`

& 

`$B1>0`

will need to evaluate to **TRUE** to make the conditional formatting work.

The `NOT(ISNUMBER($B1))` works by first determining if `$B1` is a number. `ISNUMBER($B1)` returns **TRUE** if `$B1` is a number and **FALSE** if `$B1` isn't a number (*remember, dates are numbers in Excel*). Then the`NOT` function will return the opposite of what `ISNUMBER` just determined (either **FALSE** or **TRUE**).

By then checking if `$B1` is greater than 0, you're ensuring that `$B1` contains a number that is positive and could therefore be an actual date.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use the isblank function
=and(a1< today()-28,isblank(b1))
you can use it with the opposite by using *-1 if needed

Comment: This did not work, will it make a difference that I already have 2 other conditional formats attached to the cell?

Comment: The cell is currently highlighted with other conditional formatting?

Comment: I also have a conditional format to highlight a date that is over 6 months old in black so I know it needs removing (this is set for the whole column & also includes a 'no format in blank' rule as all empty cells where filling black

Comment: You can use 2 other types of highlighting